# What happened to the Power Battery of Hal Jordan?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-tas

When the Guardian unleashed the power of hope to supercharge Killowog, Hal and the other GL' rings fighting the Red Lanterns - his power battery disappeared.
Where it is?

Comment: Which episode is this?

Comment: The Mauve Lanterns (with the power of kleptomania) pilfered it.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: the episode is *Regime change*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Blue Power Battery was later found on Mogo in the episode, Lost Planet and given to [Saint Walker](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Saint_Walker_%28Green_Lantern:_The_Animated_Series%29), an alien who would become the first Blue Lantern.

[image]